# Let Teamcity serve multiple versions of the same nuget package

Tags: nuget, teamcity-8.0

I try to have the Teamcity Nuget server provide version 1.0.0.1 and 1.0.0.2 of a package.

I built the same build configuration with different version numbers in NuGet Pack  -> Version but only the version of the latest build is listed when I check with `Get-Package -ListAvailable -Filter mycompany` in package manager console.

I also tried with one build configuration for version 1.0.0.1 and another for 1.0.0.2, but still only the package of the latest build is listed.

How can teamcity serve multiple versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the **-AllVersions** parameter. The following seems to work with Team City but not for the main nuget.org.

```
Get-Package -ListAvailable -Filter mycompany -AllVersions
```